# redis.lindex() is returning true rather than the value at the index

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I have an existing key value list: `key value1 value2`.

In `redis-cli`, I run `LRANGE key 0 -1`, which returns:

```
1) value1
2) value2
```

This confirms that the key value list exists. In `redis-cli`, running `LINDEX key 0` returns:

```
"value1"
```

However, in my node app, when I execute `console.log(redis.lindex('key', 0))`, it prints `true` rather than the value at the index.

What am I doing wrong?

Note: I'm using the `node-redis` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calls to command functions in `node-redis` are asynchronous, so they return their results in a callback and not directly from the function call.  Your call to `lindex` should look like this:

```
redis.lindex('key', 0, function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        /* handle error */
    } else {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

If you need to "return" result from whatever function you're in, you'll have to do that with a callback. Something like this:

```
function callLIndex(callback) {
    /* ... do stuff ... */

    redis.lindex('key', 0, function(err, result) {
        // If you need to process the result before "returning" it, do that here

        // Pass the result on to your callback
        callback(err, result)
    });
}
```

Which you'd call like this:

```
callLIndex(function(err, result) {
    // Use result here
});
```

Comment: So I changed my code to exactly what you have above. Except that I am returning `result` rather than logging it since I am calling the function from a different file. It's returning `undefined`. 

However, when I log it rather than return it, it logs fine. Why is it that I can log it, but not return it?

Comment: Since the function is asynchronous, you can't `return` from it. What you'll need to do is pass a callback to your function and then call that callback from inside the `redis.lindex` callback. I'll edit my answer to show an example of that.